# Need to concatenate strings from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two jQuery variables. Each variable is a text string containing words separated by a comma.

```
var myFirstVariable = green,blue
var mySecondVariable = circle,triangle
```

I would like to have a third variable retured like this:

```
var myThirdVariable = greencircle,bluecircle,greentriangle,bluetriangle
```

The order of the words in myThirdVariable is not important. But my first two variables can contain any number of words, so if

```
var myFirstVariable = green,blue,yellow
var mySecondVariable = circle,triangle,square
```

Then I need my third variable to returned like this:

```
var myThirdVariable = greencircle,bluecircle,yellowcircle,greentriangle,bluetriangle,yellowtriangle,greensquare,bluesquare,yellowsquare
```

I think I need to push() both variables into an array but I'm struggling with this area of jQuery. Hope someone can shed some light on this. Many thanks.

Comment: None of this is jquery. Its plain old javascript.

Comment: as far as I can tell, you're not even using jQuery yet

Comment: `var myThirdVariable = myFirstVariable + "," + mySecondVariable;`

Answer (score 3):

> I'm struggling with this area of jQuery

That's simply because the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) has no tools for this kind of work.

Use the native JavaScript functionality instead, specifically the [String `split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the [Array `join` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), the [string concatenation operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) and [`for`-loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
var myFirstVariable = "green,blue"
var mySecondVariable = "circle,triangle";

var firstArr = myFirstVariable.split(","),
    secondArr = mySecondVariable.split(","),
    thirdArr = [];
for (var i=0; i<firstArr.length; i++)
    for (var j=0; j<secondArr.length; j++)
        thirdArr.push(firstArr[i]+secondArr[j]);

var myThirdVariable = thirdArr.join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plain old string split method to get 2 arrays.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

You could then use nested for loops to push the new strings into your 3rd array and then use the join method to create the final string.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myFirstVariable = 'green,blue'
var mySecondVariable = 'circle,triangle'

var myThirdVariable = fn(myFirstVariable, mySecondVariable);
console.log(myThirdVariable)

function fn(fv, sv){
    var fa = fv.split(','), sa = sv.split(','), ta = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < fa.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < sa.length; j++){
            ta.push(fa[i] + sa[j])
        }
    }
    return ta.join(',')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bJcTt/)

Answer (score 0):

OK so you don't need jquery to achieve this, just JavaScript.

check out this answer here to help you:

[How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: This should be a comment and a close as dupe vote.

Comment: That's not what he wants to do